# Angular material tab scroll contents are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working with angularjs material design but I got stuck at one point that `md-scroll` for up and down is not working. However, for left and right side it is working fine. Tabs have a table view where scroll up and down is supposed to work but they are not responding. Whenever I am scrolling it up or down is it going on left direction.

This is the CSS I have used for scrolling left and right.

```
md-tabs-content-wrapper, [md-swipe-left], [md-swipe-right] {
  touch-action: none;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

Comment: A link to your webpage or a JSFiddle where we can see the problem would help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set styles for the wrong tag?

For example, I see `touch-action: none` style on `<md-tab-content>` tag on my project. And if I just set `touch-action: auto !important;` it works. It doesn't work without `!important` because of the style is set through the `style` attribute.